# 7Zip CLI Compress file with LZMA

Tags: compression, 7zip, lzma

I try to compress a file in the console with LZMA.

```
7z a -t7z output input
or
7z a -t7z -m0=lzma output input
```

However, I cannot open it on the client.

How can compress a file as an LZMA archive in the console?

It is possible the problem to be that the above commands add a file in an archive. However, I want to compress data in a data file without file structure.

Is there an option to compress a data file to a compressed data file with LZMA?

**Edit**

I see downvotes, which means the question is "not correct" in some way.

So I'll try to explain what I want to achieve.

I compress data serverside and use them on a client application. I successfully do it in Node.js like that:

```
const lzma = require('lzma');

lzma.compress(inputBuffer, 1, callback);

function callback(data, err) {
    writefile(outputPath, Buffer.from(data));
}
```

However, it is very slow. So I want to call 7Zip for the compression.

My .NET server also compresses it in a similar way.

```
byte[] barData;
using (var barStream = dukasDataHelper.SerializeLightBars(lightBars.ToArray()))
using (var zippedStream = zipLzma.Zip(barStream))
{
    barData = zippedStream.ToArray();
}
```

My problem is that I cannot set the correct options in CLI in order to be able to read the file in the client.

My client code C# is:

```
using (var blobStream = new MemoryStream(blobBytes))
using (var barStream = new ZipLzma().Unzip(blobStream))
{
    SaveDataSet(barStream, localPath);
}
```

I have this error message when compress via CLI:

```
  $exception {"Data Error"}
  Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
  at SevenZipLzma.LZMA.Decoder.Code(Stream inStream, Stream outStream, Int64 
  inSize, Int64 outSize, ICodeProgress progress)
  at SevenZipLzma.ZipLzma.Unzip(Stream stream)
```

Since the code works as I compress with Node.js and doesn't work when compressing via CLI, it means something is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

7zip makes an archive of files and directories, whereas LZMA generates a single stream of compressed data. They are not the same format. LZMA can be used *inside* a 7zip archive to compress an entry (or LZMA2 or Deflate or several other compression methods).

You can try the `xz` command to generate LZMA streams with `xz --format=lzma`.